# Cargar página concreta al enviar formulario

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Buenos días compañeros.

Os planteo una duda que tengo y no consigo resolver.

Estoy utilizando modificando un formulario de SiteOrigin en WordPress y existe un campo en el que puedo incorportar javascript que será ejecutado al pulsar el botón del formulario.

Pues bien, mi problema esta en que cuando yo indico en dicho campo el script window.open("url"), la página se abre correctamente pero en una ventana nueva y necesito que sea en la misma. He buscado información sobre el tema y se indica en mucho sitios añadir el parámetro "_self" pero aun así (window.open("url","_self")) la página no se abre en la misma pestaña.

¿ALguién tiene alguna solución para poder abrir una página concreta en la misma pestaña al realizar el envío del formulario en WordPress?

Un saludo.

Comment: El método window.open() sirve para abrir una nueva ventana con la URL especificada cargada. Lo que necesitas es una redirección. Puedes hacerla mediante la propiedad window.location.href. Ejemplo: window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

Comment: Hola Miguel. Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero eso ya lo he probado y no me funciona. Lo estoy intentando de implementar en un formulario de wordpress creado con el framework SiteOrigin y al realizar el envío aún cuando lee correctamente el script indicado lo omite y hace una redirección hacia un ancla que tiene por defecto.

¿Se te ocurreo como poder hacerlo?. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que necesitas tiene pinta de ser una de esas cosas para la que la interface del Tema no te da solución. Me temo que tendrías que buscar en el código del Tema, ver cómo gestiona el envío de emails (si usa una funcionalidad propia o por el contrario lo hace a través de un plugin como Contact Form 7) y modificar su código fuente para cuando haga un **send** te redirija a la página que deseas.